# FileNotFoundException in xamarin.forms in sqlite implementation

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.forms

In my project where i am using sqlite i get this error.

An exception of type `System.IO.FileNotFoundException occurred in SQLite.Net.Platform.WindowsPhone8.DLL but was not handled in user code`

Here is a screenshot.

[image]

P.S. i got value in variable path as C:\Data\Users\DefApps\AppData{F8267584-1051-4816-8195-EE018BA5155E}\local\Student.db3

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're missing Sqlite for Windows Phone. iOS and Android have Sqlite "build in", meaning it is available directly on the platform. Windows Phone ships without Sqlite.

To add it, first prepare your development machine by using **Tools -> Extensions and Updates** in Visual Studio. Search online for "sqlite windows phone". You must install the one for WP8 (not 8.1). When done, your machine is ready to deploy Sqlite with a WP project.

[image: Sqlite extension]

Next, add a reference to Sqlite to your WP app. Right click **References** in your WP project. Select **Add references** and in the menu select **Windows Phone SDK -> Extensions** and select *Sqlite for Windows Phone*.

[image: reference Sqlite]

Comment: I added sqlite windows phone but forgot to add reference in my wp project. Now it works. Thanks.